# Convert string array to enum on the fly

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, enums, propertygrid

I am binding an `enum` to a property grid like this:

```
public enum myEnum
{
    Ethernet,
    Wireless,
    Bluetooth
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyProperty = MyEnum.Wireless;
    }

    [DefaultValue(MyEnum.Wireless)]
    public MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PropertyGrid pg = new PropertyGrid();
    pg.SelectedObject = new MyClass();
    pg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(pg);
}
```

My problem: I get data on the fly when the program is running. I read the network adapter then store adapter names to `myArray` like this:

```
string[] myArray = new string[] { };
myArray[0] = "Ethernet";
myArray[1] = "Wireless";
myArray[2] = "Bluetooth";
```

Is possible convert `myArray` to `myEnum` on the fly using c#? Thank You.

Comment: you are assigning the myArray[] values incorrectly why are you hard coding the Enum values..?

Answer (score 12):

Sure!  This is all you need:

```
IEnumerable<myEnum> items = myArray.Select(a => (myEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), a));
```

Comment: Actually you need to cast `IEnumerable<myEnum> items = myArray.Select(a => (myEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof (myEnum), a));` otherwise you'll get a compiler error because Enum.Parse() returns an object

Answer (score 5):

If your source data is not something entirely reliable, you may want to consider converting only the items that can actually be parsed, using `TryParse()` and `IsDefined()`.

Getting an array of myEnums from an array of strings can be performed by the following code:

```
myEnum [] myEnums = myArray
    .Where(c => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(myEnum), c))
    .Select(c => (myEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), c))
    .ToArray();
```

Note that `IsDefined()` only works with a single enumerated value. If you have a `[Flags]` enum, combinations fail the test.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `Enum.Parse`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

`MyProperty = (myEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), myArray[0]);`

How you'll want to use that with your array I guess is up to your needs.

EDIT: By any chance, is it feasible to store your adapter names to your array as enumerations in the first place? Is there some reason the array *must* be strings?

Comment: I want binding myArray to Property grid and myArray looks like listbox on Propery grid, same as when binding enum type to property grid. That's why I want to convert the array into enum.

Comment: What happens when you bind an array `myEnum[] myArray = new [] {myEnum.Ethernet, myEnum.Wireless, myEnum.Bluetooth};` instead?

Comment: The problem, Enum type never existed. I get data adapter name when program runs and then store it into a string array. If string array binding to the property-grid, will be display a string-collection-editor on property grid, while I want appear like a listbox on the property-grid. That's why I want to convert a string to an enum type.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use Parse if you want to get the name of the enum's value. Don't use `.ToString()`, use this instead. For example if I want to return `Ethernet` I would do the following:

```
public enum myEnum
{
    Ethernet,
    Wireless,
    Bluetooth
}
```

In your main class add this line of code:

```
var enumName = Enum.GetName(typeof(myEnum), 0); //Results = "Ethernet"
```

If you want to enumerate over the Enum Values you could do this to get the values:

```
foreach (myEnum enumVals in Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumVals);//if you want to check the output for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enum.Parse` in the loop for each element in the array.